# Git Bash : How to move to a directory

Tags: linux, git, bash, unix

I want to change the directory but Git Bash keeps giving me this error

> ssh.exe": cd: Visual: No such file or directory

While the directory is there, as you can see from the image below. I think I am not using the right syntax to navigate to the directory. I have tried the following:

1. Checked if the folder was there using `ls`
2. Used the following command

> `cd Visual Studio 2012`

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

I am new to Git Bash so I wasn't able to figure it out.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need quote the spaces in the directory name as, by default, bash splits words at a space so visual studio 2012 will need to either be:

```
cd "Visual Studio 2012"
```

or

```
cd Visual\ Studio\ 2012
```